# Cómo usar datos fijos en JSON para la carga incial y los otros datos en memória?

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

Necesito crear un crud utilizando un Json localmente o online, con Angular 8 sin Backend.

Podrian orientarme como crear el Json para el crud?

```
Estructura del objeto persona
{
“nombre”: “Fulanoito”,
“documento”: “123456”,
“telefono”: “99123 4567”
}

Estructura del check in
{
“persona”: objPessoa,
“dataEntrada”: “2018-03-14T08:00:00”,
“dataSalida”: “2018-03-16T10:17:00”,
“agregalVeiculo”: true/false
}
```

*Las fechas usan el standar ISO-8601

Comment: Hola rodrigo. Es una pregunta amplia y con muchas posibles soluciones. Una de ellas es crear un mock server en postman: https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/mock_servers/setting_up_mock/. 


Tambien es posible para fines practicos (pero que no recomiendo) crear dentro del servicio un `observable` con un `setTimeOut()` con  un `Math. Ramdon ` para el tiempo y que puedas consultar los datos con un cierto retraso(asincrono). Guardar y modificar. Una variable que contenga lo datos de ejemplo y un poco de creatividad.

Comment: Estoy tratando de realizar con Json server. Muchas gracias,